# Как сделать 2 режима запуска программы?

Tags: c#

Есть программа, которая служит для обновления файлов. Не могу придумать, как реализовать следующее:
Если она запускается со стартом системы, то он просто должен просканировать/скачать обновления и закрыться, а если его запускает пользователь то он должен после этого еще и открыть другую программу. Как реализовать такое?

Да, можно это сделать 2-мя разными программами, однако в них будет различие только в том, что одна будет запускать после себя другую, а 2-ая нет(по факту одна строчка кода). Может быть есть более грамотное решение?

Comment: Возможно с помощью [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net) вы сможете отловить событие автозапуска и ручного запуска.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запускайте программу при старте системы с ключом коммандной строки. А ярлык для запуска пользователем сделайте без ключа.

Соответственно в программе смотрите аргументы (ключи) коммандной строки и стройте логику поведения.

Comment: Я что-то подобное и искал, но не мог вспомнить, как это называется. Спасибо.